# JSON Object using Retrofit Kotlin

Tags: api, kotlin, retrofit, datamodel

I have data from api looking like that:

```
{
"id": 2015,
"area": {
    "id": 2081,
    "name": "France"
},
"name": "Ligue 1",
"code": "FL1",
"emblemUrl": null,
"plan": "TIER_ONE",
"currentSeason": {
    "id": 499,
    "startDate": "2019-08-09",
    "endDate": "2020-05-31",
    "currentMatchday": 21,
    "winner": null
},
"seasons": [
    {
        "id": 499,
        "startDate": "2019-08-09",
        "endDate": "2020-05-31",
        "currentMatchday": 21,
        "winner": null
    },
    {
        "id": 177,
        "startDate": "2018-08-10",
        "endDate": "2019-05-25",
        "currentMatchday": 38,
        "winner": null
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "startDate": "2017-08-04",
        "endDate": "2018-05-27",
        "currentMatchday": 38,
        "winner": {
            "id": 524,
            "name": "Paris Saint-Germain FC",
            "shortName": "PSG",
            "tla": "PSG",
            "crestUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a7/Paris_Saint-Germain_F.C..svg"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 333,
        "startDate": "2016-08-12",
        "endDate": "2017-05-20",
        "currentMatchday": null,
        "winner": null
    },
    {
        "id": 334,
        "startDate": "2015-08-07",
        "endDate": "2016-05-14",
        "currentMatchday": null,
        "winner": null
    },
    {
        "id": 335,
        "startDate": "2014-08-08",
        "endDate": "2015-05-23",
        "currentMatchday": null,
        "winner": null
    },
    {
        "id": 336,
        "startDate": "2013-08-09",
        "endDate": "2014-05-17",
        "currentMatchday": null,
        "winner": null
    },
    {
        "id": 337,
        "startDate": "2012-08-10",
        "endDate": "2013-05-26",
        "currentMatchday": null,
        "winner": null
    },
    {
        "id": 338,
        "startDate": "2011-08-06",
        "endDate": "2012-05-20",
        "currentMatchday": null,
        "winner": null
    }
],
"lastUpdated": "2020-01-25T13:55:00Z"
```

}

And I try to get it in kotlin , but i dont know how to receive 'seasons' array.
Here is my kotlin class with data model

```
data class CompetitionModel(
@SerializedName("id")
val id: String?,
@SerializedName("area")
val area: AreaModel?,
@SerializedName("name")
val name: String?,
@SerializedName("code")
val code: String?,
@SerializedName("emblemUrl")
val emblemUrl: String?,
@SerializedName("plan")
val plan: String?,
@SerializedName("currentSeason")
val currentSeason: CurrentSeasonModel?,
@SerializedName("seasons")
val seasons: CurrentSeasonModel,
@SerializedName("lastUpdated")
val lastUpdated: String?

data class AreaModel(
@SerializedName("id")
val id: String = "",
@SerializedName("name")
val name: String = ""

data class CurrentSeasonModel(
@SerializedName("id")
val id: String = "",
@SerializedName("startDate")
val startDate: String = "",
@SerializedName("endDate")
val endDate: String = "",
@SerializedName("currentMatchday")
val currentMatchday: String = "",
@SerializedName("winner")
val winner: String = ""

class SeasonModel(
var seasons: CurrentSeasonModel
```

Because my SeasonModel (when i try to add []) outputs error: 
"Parameters must have type annotation" - but i have my CurrentSeasonModel as my type - what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you wanted to declare array of `CurrentSeasonModel`. In Kotlin you would declare it as `Array<CurrentSeasonModel>`, but in your use case I would recommend using `List<CurrentSeasonModel>`.